# Unir dos consultas de una misma tabla

Tags: sql-server, oracle, subconsultas

, estoy  buscando como unir dos consultas de una misma tabla, alguien me puede ayudar  y ver si esto es posible

```
Select  Grupo_id, Count(id) from student
```

junto con esta otra

```
Select  Grupo_id, Count(id) 
from students 
where City_id IN (Select id  from City where country in (Peru) )
```

espero obtener algo asi

```
Group _id , Total,  Total Pais_seleccionado
1,5,2
2,10,3
3,25, 10
```

Comment: Por favor no uses etiquetas contradictorias. SQL Server y Oracle son dos DBMS diferentes. ¿Cual de los dos usas? (Y te recomiendo usar la etiqueta de `sql` adicionalmente cuando tienes una pregunta de SQL ;-)

Comment: Cuál de los dos DBMS estás usando? SQL SERVER u Oracle? Por favor ve a [edit] la pregunta y acláralo

Answer (score 2):

Esto es relativamente simple, puedes usar un `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    Grupo_id, 
    COUNT(s.id) Total,
    COUNT(c.id) Total_Pais_Seleccionado
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN City c
    ON c.id = s.city_id
    AND c.country = 'Peru'
GROUP BY Grupo_id
ORDER BY Grupo_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de Lamak es muy buena para tu caso. Solamente escribo esta respuesta adicional, para que sabes que también hay una manera de conseguirlo que funciona con más países. Se llama agregación condicional y significa tener `CASE WHEN` en la funciona de agregación.

```
select  
  s.grupo_id,
  count(*) as total,
  count(case when c.country = 'Argentina' then 1 end) as argentina,
  count(case when c.country = 'Chile' then 1 end) as chile,
  count(case when c.country = 'Peru' then 1 end) as peru
from students s
join city c on c.id = s.city_id
group by s.grupo_id
order by s.grupo_id;
```